Determine the largest natural number r with a property
Let $n \geq 3$ be a natural number. Alex and Bogdan play the following game: in a 3x3 table, Alex fills the three cells of the first row with different numbers from the set {1,2,...n}. Then, Bogdan fills some of the cells (possibly none) in the second row with distinct numbers from the set {1,2,...,n} and the rest with 0. Finally, in each cell of the third row, the sum of the numbers in the two cells above is written.
Determine the largest natural number r with the property that, regardless of what Alex writes in the first line, Bogdan can guarantee that he can obtain in the third line, in a certain order, the terms of an arithmetic progression of ratio r.
my idea
So I made this table thinking this might help. I put some values in hope I can find some values, but I don't know what else to do.

$a_1,b_1,c_1\in {1,2,...,n}$ are the numbers put by Alex
$a_2,b_2,c_2\in {0,1,2,...,n}$ are the numbers put by Bogdan
$k-r=a_1+a_2, k=b_1+b_2, k+r=c_1+c_2$
case 1:n=3 the highest difference we can get is 2 and is attained when $(a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2)=(1,2,3,0,1,2)$
case 2: n=4  the highest difference we can get is 3 and is attained when $(a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2)=(1,2,3,0,2,4)$
Reminder that the order doesn't matter so I can just change the order of the columns

Please show your work. What have you tried? Did you try small cases? What's the largest $r$ for $n=3$? $\quad$ For all $n$, What is the largest $r$ you can get?

(Let $d$ stand for the common difference of the AP, instead of $r$ for ratio of GP.)
Hint: If Alex puts in $\{1, 2, 3 \}$, then the max difference that Bogdan can get is $ \lfloor \frac{ (n+3) - (1 + 0) } { 2 }  \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{ n+2} {2} \rfloor$
Conversely, show that regardless of what Alex puts in, Bogdan can always achieve $ D = \lfloor \frac{ n+2} {2} \rfloor$.
Note: Working with floor functions could be tricky, so you might want to split into $n$ even/odd cases.
Observation 1. If $a_1 < b_1 < c_1$, it seems reasonably to assume that we will end up with $a_1 + a_2 < b_1 + b_2 < c_1 + c_2$. We state this initially as wishful thinking, so if we can't complete the solution, we will revisit this assumption.
Observation 1b. It is tempting to further assume that $a_2 \leq b_2 \leq c_2$. However, this need not be true, and I had to revisit this assumption. (I made comments that allowed for this, but had to backtrack.)
Observation 2: To achieve $D$, what we require is
$$(c_1+c_2) - (b_1+b_2) = (b_1+b_2) - (a_1+a_2) = D.$$
Putting the unknowns to one side, we want to solve for

$ c_2 - b_2 = D - c_1 + b_1 $
$  b_2 - a_2 = D - b_1 + a_1 $

Let's define $X = D - c_1 + b_1 , Y = D - b_1 + a_1 $ to simplify the thinking.
Observation 3: If $(a_2, b_2, c_2)$ is a solution, then we could add / subtract from each term and still get a solution once we check that the bounds $[0,n]$ are satisfied.
In particular, if a solution exists, we could subtract $\min (a_2, b_2, c_2)$ from each term to get that at least one of these is 0. This leads to the following:
Wishful thinking: Now let's split by cases:

Case 1: If $Y > 0 $

Let $a_2 = 0, b_2 = Y, c_2 = X+Y$.


Case 2: $ X > 0 \geq Y$

Let $b_2 = 0, a_2 = - Y, c_2 = X$


Case 3: $ 0 \geq X, Y$

Let $c_2 = 0, b_2 = -X, a_2 = - X - Y$



It remains to show that the terms are in the bounds $[0, n]$.
Observation 4: $ n\leq 2D \leq n+2 $
Observation 5: $X+Y = 2d - c_1 + a_1 \geq 2D - n + 1  > 0  $.
So at least one of the constants is positive. In particular, case 3 does not occur so we can ignore it.
Observation 5: $X+Y = 2d - c_1 + a_1 \leq 2D - 2 \leq n$
Observation 6:  $ -n \leq D - n \leq  X \leq D - 1 \leq n$ and likewise $ - n \leq Y \leq n$.
(We could get tighter bounds of $ \approx n/2$, but that isn't required as I'm not going to chase it down.)
Hence our wishful thinking does work.
Note: I previously was looking only at cases with $Y \geq 0$, so thought that we could always use $a_2 = 0$.
I could have completed the solution (to the case of $Y \leq 0$) by using the change of variables $ a' = n+1 - a, b' = n+1  - b, c' = n+1 - c$, but that's slightly less natural than this writeup.
